# I want to increment a counter by one in a while loop c++

Tags: c++, loops, counter

I am trying to increment a lap counter in my game by one but because I have to put this code in the game loop my counter goes over every time by about 500 instead or moving up one. Here is my code. The `checkpointPassed` variable is only true when a checkpoint is passed through.  I know this works and the checkpoint number is the current checkpoint and they start at 0.

```
if(checkpointNumber == 0 && checkpointPassed == true)
{
    lapNumber += 1;
}
```

I can't post the game loop because it is quite large.

Any Help is appreciated.

**EDIT**

Here is some more of the code so you can see what I am trying to do.

```
if(distance > carRadius && markerCounter < 5000)
{
    if(checkpointPassed == true)
    {
        markerCounter++;
    }
}
if(checkpointNumber == 0 && checkpointPassed == true)
{
    lapNumber += 1;
}
if(distance < carRadius)
{
    markerCounter++;
    cross->SetX(checkpointX);
    cross->SetY(checkpointY);
    cross->SetZ(checkpointZ);
    checkpointNumber += 1;
    checkpointPassed = true;
}
if(markerCounter > 4999)
{
    checkpointPassed = false;
    cross->SetPosition(0,-50,0);
    markerCounter = 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think you've given us enough context to answer your question.  Do you ever set checkpointPassed to false?

Comment: @mydogisbox it gets set to false in a different if statement

Comment: @bobthemac You need to show more relevant code.

Comment: Does checkpointNumber ever move away from 0 during this loop? Where do conditions change? Incidentally I would get rid of the unnecessary == true and use ++lapNumber but that is just a style thing and won't fix your bug.

Comment: @CashCow yes it changes when i get to the next checkpoint it goes up to 14 and then back to 0 again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another two variable called `inCheckpoint`, which stores whether the user is currently "inside" the checkpoint or not. This allows you to detect when the user enters a checkpoint and only increment the `lapNumber` then. The code would look as follows:

```
if(checkpointNumber == 0 && checkpointPassed == true)
{
    if (inCheckpoint == false) /* previously not inside a checkpoint */
        lapNumber += 1;
    inCheckpoint = true;
}
else
{
    inCheckpoint = false;
}
```

UPDATE: Don't rely on `checkpointPassed`:

```
if(distance < carRadius)
{
    if (inCheckpoint == false) /* previously not inside a checkpoint */
        lapNumber += 1;
    inCheckpoint = true;
}
else
{
    inCheckpoint = false;
}
```

Comment: This does not work still count above it's something to do with it running the loop 1000 times a second.

Comment: The above code is "many loops per second" proof. :) I'm afraid your code for detecting checkpoints is incorrect. If `distance < carRadius`, then `checkpointPassed` would flip from 0 to 1 and back every 5000 iterations. I propose you review this. Why isn't it sufficient to have `checkpointPassed = (distance < carRadius)` ?

Comment: i think you misunderstand the code it is correct because it only changes when the distance is lower than using some vector maths to work out the distance between two objects.

Comment: Let us assume you "parked" your car so that `distance < carRadius` and let us assume that `markerCounter==0`. 1st iteration, `markerCounter` gets 1 and `checkpointPassed` gets true; 2nd iteration `markerCounter` gets 2, `checkpointPassed` stays true ... iteration 5000, `markerCounter` gets 5000, `checkpointPassed` stays true, but now `markerCounter > 4999`, so `checkpointPassed` gets **false**, `markerCounter` gets 0. As you can see, `checkpointPassed` flips despite me not moving the car at all.

Comment: what you are talking about is the timer for the cross marker it disappears at this time that all the checkpointPassed variable is used for

Comment: Okey then, I updated my answer so as not to rely on checkpointPassed anymore, but use `distance < carRadius`.

Comment: This does the same thing whenever the checkpoint number is equal to 0 it keeps counting when i only want it to count once so it will go from 0 to 2500 when it is in-between the last and first checkpoint.

Comment: In that case, you'll have to refine your question. Try to minimize the concepts that you present and the code you have to copy-paste for a full understanding.

Comment: With a some more tweaking and removing bits of code got it to work thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could set/pass a gueard value that indicates how many iterations in the game loop you are (or whether this is the first iteration).  If it is the first iteration (within the current lap), increment the variable as you do now, otherwise don't

You will need to reset this guard value for each lap -- e.g. right after you increment `lapNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to cancel the 'checkpointPassed` state.

```
if (checkpointNumber == 0 && checkpointPassed == true)
{
    lapNumber += 1;
    checkpointPassed = false;
}
```

This means that you won't be counting the lap again until the next time a checkpoint is passed, which is presumably when you need it counted.

However, if you need `checkpointPassed` true later in the loop, then you'll need to think whether you need yet another variable, such as `lapCounted`, which is set to `false` when `checkpointPassed` is set to `true`, and reset to `true` by the code above (instead of setting `checkpointPassed`, not as well as setting it).

Comment: That might be the solution, we don't have enough information to know.

Comment: @CashCow: Agreed there isn't much information to go on, though the edited question is better and strongly hints that some sort of extra variable is needed.  One of the tricks to answering questions on SO is trying to read between the lines to work out what's really at stake.

Comment: @bobthemac: you updated the question since I wrote my answer, and this was never the word-for-word solution, but just a suggestion on the general approach you should take.  With the extra code you now show, it is clear that the verbatim approach shown here is not correct, but you were never really expected to try it without thinking about how to apply it to your program.  We'll help; we can't omnisciently deduce from sub-minimal code what will really work in your full-size problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you said, your 'if' statement is inside the main loop and when you pass a checkpoint, 'checkpointPassed' becomes true. For how long?

If it stays 'true' for a few iterations, then each time your game loop does an iteration,your lap counter is incremented. In this case, you should either set checkPointPassed to false at the end of the iteration, or use a different variable, that you set to true at the same time that checkPointPassed becomes true and false after incrementing.

If this does not answer your question, can you give a little more context as with only this part of the code, it is hard to figure out what you want to do.